# NodeJs Difference between redirect and writeHead(303)

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

Quick question:
Using Node.js and wanting to redirect a user what is the difference when using

```
res.writeHead(303, {
                "Location": "/"
            });
res.end();
```

and

```
 res.redirect("/");
```

Is there any preferred method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: so I guess it's best to use `res.redirect(303, "/")` for my purpose?

Comment: If your purpose is to redirect, probably. It's certainly cleaner from a code point of view.

Answer (score 1):

As far as differences go, your first example is forcing a `303` status code, whereas the default status code will be `302` for `res.redirect()`.

Note that `303` isn't commonly used for redirects to HTTP servers.  You probably want either `301`/`302` or `307`/`308`, depending on your exact intent with the redirect.  See this for more details:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

Comment: Tho I want to use 303 because in wikipedia it says that if using 303 then the client should issue a GET request and that's just what I want.
It also says to use 303/307 when using HTTP/1.1 (which I should right?)

Comment: @nauti If you need to use `303`, use `303`, but be very sure that's what you want.  See the RFC for more details.  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.4  The key here is this:  "Note that the new URI
   in the Location header field is not considered equivalent to the
   effective request URI."